# how to do session / cookies management in Scene samsung smart tv?

Tags: session, cookies, samsung-smart-tv

Any sample code or documentation on session/cookies management in Samsung smart tv app development while using "scene" in application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Samsung TV Application running under a single-webpage architecture. All of the "scenes" will injected to index.html and becoming single instance which is "**never**" reloaded, So i never use session/cookies since all of global javascript variable will do the information sharing between scenes.

But if you want to use session/cookies for storing data after the application closed, you can use the File API to store text data in the TV and the data will "**live**" until the application uninstalled.

http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00001/index.html